# Op-amp for audio-arduino interfacing circuit

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, audio, coupling

Is it possible to use opamp of LM392 in this [circuit for interfacing audio to Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9zpC.jpg)? I had LM392 laying around so I tried it, but it doesn't work, the output is always exactly 2.50V. I am not sure if the opamp difference is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is some other issue. The LM392 op-amp should work for small input voltages (up to a volt or so peak) which isn't great but it's not zero.

Check that there is actually AC voltage at C1, and that it is the proper value. The average voltage (unless you saturate) will always be 2.5V so you won't see it with just a multimeter.

Comment: You are correct sir, there was problem in my soldering at 3 am. op-amp works well, even though it is not rail-to-rail it is enough for my needs.